# HTML/CSS layout number to the power of expression (a^x)

Tags: html, css

I need to layout some math expressions in a web page, cant use latex or mathML, just plain HTML (not HTML5)

I have an expression to the power of a different expression, for example
(a+b+sqrt(c))^(2x+b)

The second expression should be to the right of the first expression a bit smaller and above it.

Sound simple enough but I can't seem to get it right.

Any help is the styling and layout would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

HTML is rather limited when it comes to mathematical expressions. In principle, HTML specifications suggest that you use `sup` element for superscripts, so the sample expression would be

```
(<i>a</i> + <i>b</i> + √<i>c</i>)<sup>2<i>x</i> + <i>b</i></sup>
```

However, the implementations of `sup` in browsers are inconsistent and generally poor (causing e.g. uneven line spacing), so it is pragmatically better to use the `span` element with a class instead:

```
(<i>a</i> + <i>b</i> + √<i>c</i>)<span class=sup>2<i>x</i> + <i>b</i></span>
```

with CSS code like

```
.sup {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1ex; 
  font-size: 80%;
}
```

Some reasons are explained on my page [Math in HTML (and CSS)](https://jkorpela.fi/math/). Also consider JavaScript-based libraries for pages containing complicated math expressions:

- [KaTeX](http:///home/jarvisd/work/resume/climate-report.pdf)
- [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/)
- [jqMath](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html)

The sample expression is a borderline case; it would look mathematically more correct if the square root were represented using a square root symbol with [vinculum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinculum_(symbol)) and not just √*c*, and trying to construct a vinculum using  HTML and CSS gets rather dirty, but otherwise it can be reasonably handled with HTML and CSS.

Comment: I have intentionally used `i` elements and I just rolled back edits that incorrectly changed it to `em`. First, changing someone else’s answer to please your idea of “semantic markup” is just wrong, even if you were right about the “semantics”. Second, HTML specs disagree on what `em` means, but they all refer to emphasis of some kind. The use ot italic for variables in mathematics is conventional notation, not emphasis of any kind. If you really wanted to use “semantic” markup, then `var` would be much much closer.

Comment: Hi, it looks like the link to  Math in HTML (and CSS) is broken. Can you fix it or any other references recommend? Thanks.

Answer (score 32):

HTML defines a `<sup>` tag for superscript. For example:

```
a<sup>x</sup>
```

of which you can alter the margins and vertical alignment with CSS.

Comment: Is this <sup> tag supported only HTML5 or it was supported in older HTML versions also ?

Comment: The <sup> tag goes way back before I was online. My first knowledge of it was in the [HTML 4 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.2.3) which of course preceded the days of XHTML and today's HTML 5 but the first reference I can find of it is in the [HTML 3 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32#font-style) from 1997. So it's safe to say that it's also for older HTML versions.

Comment: thanks for providing info. Now I will use it in my website without worrying about older browsers in world.

Comment: Simple and straighforward answer. Nice!

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `<sup>` element to display the exponent as a superscript of the base. The HTML involved would be:

```
(a+b+sqrt(c))<sup>(2x+b)</sup>
```

A better approach would be to use CSS to achieve the same result, for which you can use a span with the property:

```
vertical-align:super;
```

A demonstration can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sTqtu/).

Answer (score 2):

Subscript and Superscript character character can be specified by the sub and sup.

```
X<sub>2</sub><sup>3</sup>
```

This gives X suffix 2 and power 3. This is the easy way to give power to the number in html.