# How to Show x^n as x power n in fpdf?

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to print MySQL table and it contains a few values in

```
X^n
```

format. I want to print them in pdf report as

```
X<sup>n</sup>
```

How to do that?

I want it in PDF report, not in an HTML page. I have no problem with showing with  tag in an HTML page.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML/CSS layout number to the power of expression (a^x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875645/html-css-layout-number-to-the-power-of-expression-ax)

Comment: I tried this subWrite function http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script61.php but it is taking so much effort to check if value and split the value.